# How to Install Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04 (Ubuntu Pre-Installed)

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

How can I install Windows 7 with my Ubuntu 12.04 x64 side by side a.k.a. dual-boot? I don't want to format and lose my Ubuntu data. I tried to install windows 7 (Ubuntu pre-installed) in a virtual machine (with VirtualBox). It gave me an error:

> Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition. See the Setup log files for more information.

Either installation process of windows 7 over pre-installed Ubuntu with dual boot or how to backup and restore whole Ubuntu system will solve my problem.

My system has one 128 GB SSD (sda) which have Ubuntu installed on it and one 1.0 TB hard disc (sdb).

sda has:

- sda1 (linux, bootable, Ext4, /)
- sda2 (extended)
- sda5 (linux swap)

sdb has:

- sdb1 (Microsoft Reserved Partition)
- sdb2 (Linux Basic Data Partition,-,NTFS,/media/New Volume)
- sdb3 (EFI System Partition,-,FAT32,Not mounted)
- sdb4 (EFI System Partition,-,FAT32,Not mounted)
- sdb5 (Linux Basic Data Partition,-)
- sdb6 (Linux Basic Data Partition,-,NTFS,/media/New Volume 2)
- sdb7 (Swap Space, Linux Swap Partition)

Comment: Is this a duplicate? The OP is asking regarding a specific issue not addressed in the duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Install Windows in the partition that you have set aside. Windows will install it's own bootloader and that's ok. Two ways to fix the bootloader include:

Easy BCD: This is a great tool for editing the boot menu. You don't have to pay for it (I would recommend donating though...) and it works well. This is a preferable option if you need to get a dual boot working with the Windows bootloader. I haven't tried to edit GRUB with it, but I think there's that option.

Boot-Repair: Boot up your system with an installation disk and choose the Try Ubuntu option. Add the repository, install boot-repair and it will give you some powerful options for modifying GRUB. boot-repair instructions can be found here: [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

I would recomend the Easy BCD route. I've had the most success with it and it's pretty simple to figure out. That's all I got, so good luck and have fun :D

Comment: Oh the link for EasyBCD: [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)` Just go to the bottom and click on register. If you want you can enter your email, but you don't have to. Just hitting the download button works.

Comment: The OP asked regarding a specific issue (the system partition) which is not addressed here.